# Isomorphism between endomorphism rings and matrix rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

I have tried to solve undermentioned problem.

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$ with a countable basics $\{{v_n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$.
Let $R = \mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{F}}(V)$.
I want to prove that $R \cong M_n (R)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, where $M_n (R)$ is the matrix rings of order $n$ over the ring $R$.

I would like to use the well-known fact that if $R$ is a finite direct sum of $R_n$ then $R \cong M_n(R)$.
It might be worth trying to build a decomposition of $R = \mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{F}}(V)$ in a finite direct sum of $R_n$.

My solution attempts. Let $x \in V$.
There is only one decomposition of it $x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n v_n$ in the basis.
Consider any homomorphism $\varphi \in R$. Then $\varphi(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \varphi(x_n v_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n \varphi(v_n)$.
Let us define endomorphisms $\varepsilon_i$ by the rule $\varepsilon_i\big(\varphi(v_j)\big) = \delta_{ij}$. We have $\varepsilon(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n\varepsilon_n(x)$.

But the problem is that this is not a finite direct sum. How can to decompose $\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{F}}(V)$ into a finite direct sum?

Answer (score 1):

We have an isomorphism of vector spaces $V \cong V^n$, inducing an isomorphism of right $R$-modules
$$R = \hom_{\mathbb{F}}(V,V) \cong \hom_{\mathbb{F}}(V,V^n) \cong \hom_{\mathbb{F}}(V,V)^n =  R^n.$$
Hence,
$$R \cong \mathrm{End}_R(R) \cong \mathrm{End}_R(R^n) \cong M_n(R).$$

Comment: How does homomorphism $V \cong V^n$ work?

Comment: Please think about it.

Comment: Do you mean that we associate any vector $x \in V$ with a string of its coordinates in the basis $v_n$?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Both $V$ and $V^2$ are vector spaces with a countably infinite basis, hence they are isomorphic. In fact, a basis of $V^2$ is $\{(v_i,0) : i \geq 1\} \cup \{(0,v_j) : j \geq 1\}$, so $\cong \mathbb{N} \sqcup \mathbb{N} \cong \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: If you have further questions about this basic isomorphism, I suggest to ask a separate question (but please do your research before that).